# iOS voip app not responding in background mode after 5 minute

Tags: ios, sockets, voip, pjsip, kamailio

I am developing a iOS (7 & 8) VOIP application (By using Kamailio server and PJSIP device library).

Everything works fine when application is in foreground, but the issue is when application is in background, the socket will remain alive for only 5 minute (300 sec).
When I am registering with:

```
[application setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler: ^{
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(keepAlive) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }];
```

I am able to get the call.

The issue is `setKeepAliveTimeout` is 10 minutes and socket only persists for 5 minutes.

I enabled "*App provides Voice over IP services*"  in `.plist`. I also set `PJSUA_REG_INTERVAL` to 600 seconds.
Please help me set the VIOP socket in PJSIP.

Comment: followed the link  i think you will get answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028682/ios-backgrounding-not-working/29846231#29846231

Comment: I already did this, but no luck.

Comment: How I cna use CFReadStreamRef in PJSIP?

Comment: I am getting  error:  Received 50 consecutive errors: 120035 for the accept() operation, stopping further ioqueue accepts.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try assigning the VoIP property to the Stream as below,

```
CFReadStreamSetProperty((__bridge_retained CFReadStreamRef)iStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
```

Comment: As per document PJSIP internally doing that. Correct me If I am not wrong.

Comment: I am using pjsua_acc_set_registration, for reregistration, it is also acting funny, some time it is giving 408,503 errors while app is in background.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know about PJSIP.

Comment: Thanks, for answer, PJSIP internally doing this.

Answer (score 0):

NAT of some Internet providers shutdown inactive sockets after a few minutes of silence.

It's possible to activate internal keep-alive messages for sockets in the PJSIP with following code:

```
pjsip_cfg()->tcp.keep_alive_interval = 90;
pjsip_cfg()->tls.keep_alive_interval = 90;
```

And of course you have to set up iOS keep-alive timer.